# Using Google Analytics, if I explicitly log an event using _trackPageview, does that count as a 'real' page view?

Tags: google-analytics

For example, if I have a news page that's already being tracked via GA and I add a javascript event to capture clicks on a specific link to the news page (e.g. navigation) am I then 'double counting'?

Comment: Short answer - "Yes". As far as GA is concerned, it is logged as an additional page view - there is no way in GA to tell the difference between a "real" pageview and a "virtual" pageview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a fake pageview is not beneficial in this situation, and from your description that you're looking to track an engagement click on your page, use Event Tracking instead of Pageviews.

**Tracking a click/event is easy (especially if you're already using Javascript).  The best part is that this event is *not* considered a page view, keeping those stats safe.**

The implementation is simple and allows for quite a bit of customization:

_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value)

Below is an example of a link that's been encoded with an event tag:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);">Play</a>
```

Here's the Google Analytics resource page on Event Tagging:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks - will mark accepted as soon as Google gets around to providing me with my data :)

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not a real page view, but Google Analytics thinks that it is--i.e., it shows up in your pageview counts.

Fortunately, it's easy to filter those so they don't contaminate your pageview data.

So for instance,

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'unique_virtual_pagename']);
```

So in your GA Browser, you'll see the number of clicks actually shown as the number of pageviews of *unique_virtual_pagename*, which is not good.

There are a two ways to fix this (that i am aware of): (i) set a temporary filter at the bottom of the pageview table; or (ii) set a persistent (c*ustom*) *filter* in your Admin Panel (which i think is best) to remove pageviews having only the name *unique_virtual_pagename*, or whatever name you've chosen. This will of course take up to 24 hours to set, so the best plan is to set the filter first, *then* add the javascript to your page. so the filter is active when you begin collecting clicks.

But that just solves the problem of disaggregating these virtual pageviews from your real pageviews, you still need a way to count/record them.

I prefer to create a separate *profile* in these cases. So first, i filter the virtual pageviews from my actual pageviews using a custom filter, then i create a new profile which has another filter excluding everything but these virtual pageviews. I usually give that profile a name based on the event.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. So, to confirm, such pageviews WILL be included in absolute top-level counts, such as total page views per day, right? I guess a filter, combined with a global prefix (e.g. /fake/) is definitely the way to go for accurate tracking.

Comment: ... although, won't a persistent filter remove all trace of the original event and completely defeat the purpose?

Comment: it does remove the event--but your question didn't mention the next step, so i amended my answer just now to with the technique i use in these cases. There might be a better way, but i know this works.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is registering what's called a 'virtual page view'. To GA it's seen as a real page view and shows up in your content report's and page view counts etc. This is often useful if you want to show a page view for media that GA can't track. It's also commonly used to count an event, such as a button click, as a goal conversion.

If you just want to record the event and not count a page view you should look at using GA event tracking instead.